# Game infrastructure NOT working properly (c++)

Tags: c++, class, object, visual-c++

I have been designing my c++ console game and I have a question about the game loop. Whenever the game loops, I end up reinitializing my velocity variables in the constructor which sets them to "0". I have a couple ideas on how to solve this but it ends up ruining my game infrastructure and after a while gets confusing.
Can someone please tell me how to prevent my velocity variables from being reinitialized.
BTW I'll find out how to group my headers better later.

`FPS.timerMilli(1)` is a function that counts 1 millisecond before exiting function. (Trying to control FPS).

**rectangle.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#include "rectangle.h"


void rectangle::rectangleDrawPos(int h, int k) {

    // Draw top of rectangle
    for (int verticle = 1; verticle <= h; verticle += 1) {
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    for (int horizontal = 1; horizontal <= h; horizontal += 1) {
        std::cout << " ";
    }
    for (int x = 1; x <= width; x += 1) {
        std::cout << ".";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    //Number of sides
    midWidth = width - 2;
    for (int y = 1; y <= height; y+=1) {

    //Draw sides
        for (int x = 1; x <= h; x += 1) {
            std::cout << " ";
        }

        std::cout << ":";
        for (int x = 1; x <= midWidth; x+=1) {
            std::cout << " ";
        }
        std::cout << ":\n";
    }

    //Bottom of rectangle
    for (int x = 1; x <= h; x += 1) {
        std::cout << " ";
    }
    for (int x = 1; x <= width; x += 1) {
        std::cout << ".";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}



//constructor
rectangle::rectangle(int locHeight, int locWidth) {
    width = locWidth;
    height = locHeight;

}
```

**rectangle.h:**

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H


class rectangle {
    //Variables
    int height, width, midWidth;

public:

    //functions
    void rectangleDrawPos(int h, int k);

    //constructor
    rectangle(int locHeight, int locWidth);
};


#endif
```

**MyGame.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>

#include "timer.h"
#include "config.h"
#include "IOMovement.h"
#include "rectangle.h"

int main(){
    //object def
    timer FPS;
    config startupConfig;
    IOMovement IO;

    //config
    startupConfig.Set_Consol_Size(startupConfig.half_screen_Size, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
    startupConfig.Position_Consol(-6, 0);

    //Game Loop
    while (1==1) {
        FPS.timerMilli(1);

         //Game Startup
        IO.IOStartup();

        //map


        //ai
    }

    //exit
    return 0;
}
```

**IOMovement.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#include "IOMovement.h" 
#include "rectangle.h"

#define W_KEY 0x57
#define S_KEY 0x53
#define A_KEY 0x41
#define D_KEY 0x44
#define R_KEY 0x52


void IOMovement::IO() {
    rectangle player(15, 5);

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(W_KEY)) {
            system("CLS");
            velocityVerticle--;

            player.rectangleDrawPos(velocityHorizontal, velocityVerticle);
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(S_KEY)) {
            system("CLS");
            velocityVerticle++;
            std::cout << "Working\n";
            player.rectangleDrawPos(velocityHorizontal, velocityVerticle);
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(A_KEY)) {
            system("CLS");
            velocityHorizontal--;

            player.rectangleDrawPos(velocityHorizontal, velocityVerticle);
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(D_KEY)) {
            system("CLS");
            velocityHorizontal++;

            player.rectangleDrawPos(velocityHorizontal, velocityVerticle);
        }

}


void IOMovement::IOStartup() {
    //Variable decleration
    velocityVerticle = 0;
    velocityHorizontal = 0;

    //Functions
    IO();
}
```

**IOMovement.h:**

```
#ifndef IOMOVEMENT_H
#define IOMOVEMENT_H

class IOMovement {
    int velocityVerticle, velocityHorizontal;
    bool variableInitialization;

    void IO();

public:
    void IOStartup();
};



#endif
```

Comment: What is the question ? Ask a question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In comment by VishaalShankar, I'd like to stress the *M*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need your variable to retain it's value you could turn them into static variables.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed the problem!